# hexadecimal (bytes) to binary (uint) in a smart contract

Tags: solidity, assembly

What are some ways to convert from `bytes8` hexadecimal to `uint64` binary?

Answer (score 1):

You can just cast it:

```
function test(bytes8 b) public pure returns (uint64) {
    return uint64(b);
}
```