# Solidity: Conversion bytes memory to uint

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle-compile

Is there a workaround to convert a bytes memory to uint256?

Comment: Duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41944/hexadecimal-bytes-to-binary-uint-in-a-smart-contract

Comment: Actually is not the same question, since bytes is a dynamically-sized byte array, while bytes8 is not.

Comment: Indeed trying to do the same of ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41944/ we have the following compiler error: 
" TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes memory" to "uint256"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible but there's no easy way to do it. You either have to do some bitwise xor and shifting to build the uint, or use inline assembly to `mload`.

Here's the working code, feel free to copy paste

```
function sliceUint(bytes bs, uint start)
    internal pure
    returns (uint)
{
    require(bs.length >= start + 32, "slicing out of range");
    uint x;
    assembly {
        x := mload(add(bs, add(0x20, start)))
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works great, thanks @libertylocked

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast bytes to uint256, since bytes is a dynamically-sized byte array.

If you really need to do this conversion, use bytes32 (or any other fixed sized byte array) instead of bytes and then convert it to uint256 by a simple cast:

```
function two(bytes32 inBytes) pure public returns (uint256 outUint) {
      return uint256(inBytes);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to work with dynamically-sized byte array. 

Another question: Is not possible to cast dynamically-sized byte array to  fixed sized byte array?

Comment: Think about this: how can you to convert a dynamically-sized array thats bigger then a fixed sized array? It won't fit ;)

Comment: this doesn't work in solc 0.5.x, any idea how to convert fixed size byte arrays to and from uint?

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to simply cast bytes memory to string and then use the stringToUint function I found in the Answer: [How to convert string to int](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10932/how-to-convert-string-to-int).